# Dynamic Theme Toggle in Next.js App Using Ant Design v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, antd

I am working on a Next.js application with Ant Design v5 and I'm trying to implement a dynamic theme toggle to switch between light and dark modes. I've encountered a issue: the theme settings work correctly on initial load, but subsequent changes to the `isDarkMode` state don't seem to have any effect. Here's the updated part of my code in the `layout.tsx` file:

```js
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ConfigProvider, Layout, theme as antdTheme, Switch } from "antd";
import { Content } from "antd/es/layout/layout";
import { BulbFilled, CloudFilled } from "@ant-design/icons";

const PublicLayout = ({ children }) => {
  const { defaultAlgorithm, darkAlgorithm } = antdTheme;
  const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = (checked) => {
    setIsDarkMode(prevValue => !prevValue);
  };

  return (
    <ConfigProvider
      theme={{
        algorithm: isDarkMode ? darkAlgorithm : defaultAlgorithm,
      }}
    >
      <Layout>
        <StyledHeader>
          <Switch
            checkedChildren={<BulbFilled />}
            unCheckedChildren={<CloudFilled />}
            onChange={handleClick}
          />
        </StyledHeader>
        <Content>{children}</Content>
      </Layout>
    </ConfigProvider>
  );
};

export default PublicLayout;
```

Initially, the theme is set based on the `isDarkMode` state, but when I toggle the switch, although the `isDarkMode` state changes (as I verified through console logs), the theme does not update as expected. I suspect the issue might be related to SSR and how I'm applying the theme in `ConfigProvider`, or maybe something else is missing in my approach to state management and theme application.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can identify what I might be doing wrong? Any insights or suggestions to fix this issue would be immensely helpful!

Comment: Take a look into [antd ssr documentation](https://ant.design/docs/react/server-side-rendering)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding [package](https://github.com/ant-design/nextjs-registry) `@ant-design/nextjs-registry`, it works like a charm.

Comment: So you had to add a package that you are not using in your code at all ?

Comment: Add package and wrap code like `ant design` team described in their [instruction](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-next)